# cassandra where clause .could not find proper rows

Tags: cassandra

i have a coulmn family in cassandra 1.2 as below:

```
 time            | class_name                  | level_log | message       | thread_name
-----------------+-----------------------------+-----------+---------------+-------------
 121118135945759 | ir.apk.tm.test.LoggerSimple |     DEBUG | This is DEBUG |        main
 121118135947310 | ir.apk.tm.test.LoggerSimple |     ERROR | This is ERROR |        main
 121118135947855 | ir.apk.tm.test.LoggerSimple |      WARN |  This is WARN |        main
 121118135946221 | ir.apk.tm.test.LoggerSimple |     DEBUG | This is DEBUG |        main
 121118135951461 | ir.apk.tm.test.LoggerSimple |      WARN |  This is WARN |        main
```

when i use this query:

```
SELECT * FROM LogTM WHERE token(time) > token(0);
```

i get nothing!!! but as you see all of time values are greater than zero!

this is CF schema:

```
  CREATE TABLE logtm(
        time bigint PRIMARY KEY ,
        level_log text ,
        thread_name text ,
        class_name text ,
        msg text 
  );
```

can any body help?

thanks :)

Comment: Post your schema, and which partitioner you're using.

Comment: Why are you using token? If you hash 0 with token then the output wont be 0.

Comment: i think the partitioner must be Murmur3Partitioner (default), becouse i didn't change it.

Comment: when i use query with out token (SELECT * FROM LogTM WHEREtime >0;).
i get this error:
Bad Request: Only EQ and IN relation are supported on the partition key for random partitioners (unless you use the token() function)
Perhaps you meant to use CQL 2? Try using the -2 option when starting cqlsh.

Comment: That message is telling you that you can't do comparison operations (larger than, smaller than) on partition keys (a.k.a. row keys), i.e. the first column in your `PRIMARY KEY` clause, e.g. `time` in your case.

Answer (score 4):

If you're not using an ordered partitioner (if you don't know what that means you don't) that query doesn't do what you think. Just because two timestamps sort one way doesn't mean that their tokens do. The token is the (Murmur3) hash of the cell value (unless you've changed the partitioner).

If you need to do range queries you can't do it on the partition key, only on clustering keys. One way you can do it is to use a schema like this:

```
CREATE TABLE LogTM (
  shard INT,
  time INT,
  class_name ASCII,
  level_log ASCII,
  thread_name ASCII,
  message TEXT,
  PRIMARY KEY (shard, time, class_name, level_log, thread_name)
)
```

If you set `shard` to zero the schema will be roughly equivalent to what you're doing now, but the query `SELECT * FROM LogTM WHERE timestamp > 0` will give you the results you expect.

However, the performance will be awful. With a single value of `shard` only a single partition/row will be created, and you will only use a single node of your cluster (and that node will be very busy trying to compact that single row).

So you need to figure out a way to spread the load across more nodes. One way is to pick a random shard between something like 0 and 359 (or 0 and 255 if you like multiples of two, the exact range isn't important, it just needs to be an order of magnitude or so larger than the number of nodes) for each insert, and read from all shards when you read back: `SELECT * FROM LogTM WHERE shard IN (0,1,2,...)` (you need to include all shards in the list, in place of `...`).

You can also pick the shard by hashing the message, that way you don't have to worry about duplicates.

You need to tell us more about what exactly it is that you're trying to do, especially how you intend to query the data. Don't go do the thing I described above, it is probably completely wrong for your use case, I just wanted to give you an example so that I could explain what is going on inside Cassandra.

Comment: i dont know what is partitioner exactly! can you explain it?

Comment: @zahra not enough room in the comments, and also its explained by someone that knows more than me [here](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.2/cluster_architecture/partitioners)

Comment: how can i found what partitioner i am using?

Comment: The `partitioner` setting in cassandra.yaml. Default is `org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner`

Comment: what is default number of nodes in cluster if i dont change cassandra.yaml file ever?

Comment: i create schema as this:
CREATE TABLE test( level_log text ,time bigint,  thread_name text , class_name text , msg text, PRIMARY KEY(level_log, time));
and query in this way:   SELECT * FROM test WHERE time >0 ALLOW FILTERING;
is it okay? i get the result i expected. is the only problem bad performance?

Comment: I can't say if the performance will be good enough, it will depend a lot on what it is that you're trying to achieve. If you need to run the query 10000 times per second, probably not, if you only need to run it once per minute almost anything will be good enough.

Comment: The schema in your comment might work, but the query will not. You must include `level_log` in the query, just filtering on `time > 0` will not be good enough. And `level_log` will probably not have enough distinct values to spread the load across the nodes. You need something with more possible values, maybe `thread_name` or `class_name` (but I guess those are problematic for other reasons).

Comment: thanks alot for your help Theo:). for last question :what is default number of nodes in cluster if i dont change cassandra.yaml file ever?

Comment: A node is a machine running Cassandra, so the number of nodes is the size of your cluster. There is another thing called vnodes, but that is not what I mean by "nodes".

Comment: when i use test cluster i have only one node,right? in this case all of rows are saved in one node,so why i cant use range query on partition key?

Comment: Cassandra doesn't care if the cluster has one node or many, it works the same way when there is only one node or hundreds. Just because you have one node it won't let you do things that wouldn't work when you add more nodes. You're trying to do something that Cassandra isn't designed to do, don't do range queries on partition keys, model your problem differently.